# XGBoost poor calibration for binary classification on a dataset with high class imbalance

Tags: boosting, unbalanced-classes, calibration

I've read a lot of threads/questions about this issue and I got conflicting answers.

I've trained an XGBoost model on tabular data to predict the risk for a specific event (ie a binary classifier). There are 43169 subjects and only 1690 events. I've taken into account this class imbalance with XGBoost's scale_pos_weight parameter. Hyperparameters were optimized with Bayesian Optimization (note: I have the same problem on a model without optimization).

I'm getting a reasonably well-discriminating model, however calibration looks awful: [image: XGBoost model calibration]

Calibration using sklearn's sklearn.calibration.CalibratedClassifierCV doesn't improve the calibration at all (Isotonic and Sigmoid). It looks like XGBoost models cannot be calibrated with these methods.

My questions are:

- Did I do anything obviously wrong (see my code below)?
- Should I try another calibration method?
- Should I try another model (SVM, kNN, ...) and which one could be the most interesting considering that high class imbalance? I always thought that XGBoost was the gold-standard for tabular data. I've created several other models, including on data with class imbalance, and never got such poor calibration.

Thank you!

## Load libraries

```
import pickle
import numpy as np
import warnings
warnings.simplefilter(action='ignore', category=FutureWarning)
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib as pl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.gridspec import GridSpec
%matplotlib inline
import xgboost as xgb
import sklearn
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split, StratifiedKFold, cross_val_score
from sklearn.metrics import brier_score_loss, accuracy_score, average_precision_score, precision_score, recall_score, f1_score, roc_auc_score, make_scorer, roc_curve, auc, precision_recall_curve, confusion_matrix, plot_confusion_matrix
from sklearn.calibration import CalibratedClassifierCV, calibration_curve, CalibrationDisplay
from bayes_opt import BayesianOptimization
```

## Create a held-out dataset

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(
    X,
    y,
    test_size=0.20,
    random_state=7,
    stratify = y
 )
```

## Create a 5-fold stratified cross-validation

```
cv = StratifiedKFold(
    n_splits=5,
    shuffle=True,
    random_state=42
    )
```

## Bayesian hyperparameters optimization

### Define hyperparameters to explore and their limits

```
pbounds = {
    'learning_rate': (0.01, 1.0),
    'n_estimators': (10, 1000),
    'min_child_weight':(1, 10),
    'max_depth': (3,12),
    'subsample': (0, 1),  # Change for big datasets
    #'colsample': (0, 1.5),  # Change for datasets with lots of features
    'colsample_bytree': (0.3, 1),
    'gamma': (0, 5),
    'reg_alpha':(1e-5, 0.75),
    'reg_lambda':(1e-5, 0.45)}
```

### Create the function to optimize

```
def xgboost_hyper_param(learning_rate,
                        n_estimators,
                        min_child_weight,
                        max_depth,
                        subsample,
                        #colsample,
                        colsample_bytree,
                        gamma,
                        reg_alpha,
                        reg_lambda):
    
    max_depth = int(max_depth)
    n_estimators = int(n_estimators)
    
    clf = xgb.XGBClassifier(
        objective='binary:logistic',
        eval_metric = 'auc',
        #tree_method = 'gpu_hist',
        #gpu_id = 0,
        use_label_encoder=False,
        booster = 'gbtree',
        scale_pos_weight = 24,
        learning_rate = learning_rate,
        n_estimators = n_estimators,
        min_child_weight = min_child_weight,
        max_depth = max_depth,
        subsample = subsample,
        #colsample = colsample,
        colsample_bytree = colsample_bytree,
        gamma = gamma,
        reg_alpha = reg_alpha,
        reg_lambda = reg_lambda
        )
    return np.mean(cross_val_score(clf, X_train, y_train, cv=cv, scoring='roc_auc'))

    optimizer = BayesianOptimization(
        f=xgboost_hyper_param,
        pbounds=pbounds,
        random_state=1,
)
```

## Launch nested cross-validation for Bayesian Optimization

```
optimizer.maximize(init_points=20,
                  n_iter=5)
```

### Get the best parameters

```
params = optimizer.max['params']
print("Here are the best parameters:")
print(params)
```

### Converting the max_depth and n_estimator values from float to int

```
params['max_depth']= int(params['max_depth'])
params['n_estimators']= int(params['n_estimators'])
```

## Create model

```
evals_result ={}
eval_set = [(X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test)]

LungCancerRisk = xgb.XGBClassifier(

    **params,
    objective='binary:logistic',
    tree_method = 'exact',
    booster = 'gbtree',
    eval_metric=["auc"],
    scale_pos_weight = 24,
    eval_set=eval_set,
    use_label_encoder=False)

LungCancerRisk.fit(
    X_train,
    y_train,
    eval_set=eval_set
)
```

## Assess calibration

```
clf_list = [
    (LungCancerRisk, "XGBoost"),
]

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))
gs = GridSpec(4, 2)
colors = plt.cm.get_cmap("Dark2")

ax_calibration_curve = fig.add_subplot(gs[:2, :2])
calibration_displays = {}
for i, (clf, name) in enumerate(clf_list):
    clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
    display = CalibrationDisplay.from_estimator(
        clf,
        X_test,
        y_test,
        n_bins=10,
        name=name,
        ax=ax_calibration_curve,
        color=colors(i),
    )
    calibration_displays[name] = display

ax_calibration_curve.grid()
ax_calibration_curve.set_title("Calibration plots")

grid_positions = [(2, 0), (2, 1), (3, 0), (3, 1)]
for i, (_, name) in enumerate(clf_list):
    row, col = grid_positions[i]
    ax = fig.add_subplot(gs[row, col])

    ax.hist(
        calibration_displays[name].y_prob,
        range=(0, 1),
        bins=10,
        label=name,
        color=colors(i),
    )
    ax.set(title=name, xlabel="Mean predicted probability", ylabel="Count")

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2):

I think it's a pretty well-known thing that gradient boosted decision trees have a tendency towards poor calibration. However, what you get looks pretty extreme. Part of the answer is right there [in the XGBoost documentation](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/param_tuning.html), where it says:"If you care about predicting the right probability [...] in such a case, you cannot re-balance the dataset" (i.e. you should not use `scale_pos_weight`). I suspect if you avoid using it, you could get a predictions that can be calibrated a bit more reasonably.

In terms of other models, I would usually expect some form of logistic regression to be reasonably well calibrated out-of-the-box.